# Install GTK+ >= 3.16 with PyGObject bindings on MacOS 10.15

Tags: macos, gtk

when I'm typing the command

```
brew install pygobject3 --with-python@2 gtk+3
```

I'm always getting the error message

```
invalid option --with-python@2
```

I'm getting the same error message when I want to run the gtk+3 under mac os 10.15

```
Namespace Gtk not available
```

Maybe the Version of 10.15 of MacOS the problem....

```
gtk+3 version 3.24.12 and pygobject3 Version 3.34.0 are installed. 


Installation of homebrew for MacOS
gtk+3 version 3.24.12 and pygobject3 Version 3.34.0 are installed.
Python3.7 is installed

File "...anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 129, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
```

I would like to run the program DemonEditor on MacOS 10.15 (Catalina)
to make some settings of my engima2 satellite receiver, for this I need the requirements "GTK+ >= 3.16 with PyGObject bindings".

Maybe some of the experts can help me.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Since I am the author of this program, I am forced to report that since the program is designed for Linux, it will not work on MacOS without minor changes to the program itself. But still it’s possible.
[DemonEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJlMX.png)

Тo resolve dependencies, it is enough to install as follows:

```
brew install gtk+3 pygobject3 adwaita-icon-theme
pip3 install requests
```

**Upd.**
I created an experimental [brunch](https://github.com/DYefremov/DemonEditor/tree/experimental-mac) and added small changes to the program for the possibility of testing the launch in the MacOS. Perhaps not all the functionality will work (I have not tested it), but the program should start.

Gud luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your answer. Unfortunately I'm getting always the same ErrorValue *ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available* Maybe I'm using the false python environment, do I need to set the right path? I don't know...

Answer (score 2):

STRIKE. It works, I can start the DemonEditor-GUI under 10.15. I have remove all packages via the

```
brew remove --force $(brew list)
```

installed the three packages again, via

```
brew install python3 gtk+3 pygobject3 adwaita-icon-theme
```

BUT. The most important step was to add the "Installation folder" of the brew packages to my python path but execute the comand

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages.
```

My assumption is, that due to fact, that I have installed an own conda-environment for python37, the site-packages have to be added to the path.

Big thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

On my test system, I did not set any paths or environment variables! Just installed python 3 with the command:

```
brew install python3
```

Then I installed the dependencies as described above.Then I downloaded the archive from [here](https://github.com/DYefremov/DemonEditor/archive/experimental-mac.zip), and in the unpacked folder of the program I simply gave the command:

```
./start.py
```

Below is the output of the commands `python3 --version` and `brew list`
Compare with your list, perhaps this will somehow help identify the missing components.

```
python3 --version
Python 3.7.4

brew list
adwaita-icon-theme  libepoxy
atk                 libffi
cairo               libpng
fontconfig          librsvg
freetype            libtiff
fribidi             lzo
gdbm                openssl@1.1
gdk-pixbuf          pango
gettext             pcre
glib                pixman
gobject-introspection       pkg-config
graphite2           py2cairo
gsettings-desktop-schemas   py3cairo
gtk+3               pygobject3
harfbuzz            python
hicolor-icon-theme      python@2
icu4c               readline
jpeg                sqlite
libcroco            xz
```

**Upd.** For the experiment, I removed all my packages with the command:

```
brew remove --force $(brew list)
```

Then again installed by commands as described above

```
brew install python3 gtk+3 pygobject3 adwaita-icon-theme
```

Working!